# How to quote a string containing dollar sign $ and single quote '?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

My directory's name contains a `$` and `'`, for example

```
:~$ export DIR=\$my\'dir
:~$ sh -c "ls $DIR"
```

How can I run above command without `$my` being expanded? I know the single quote doesn't work since the `$DIR` contains one.

Actually, the question came from using `find` command as follows:

```
:~$ find ./\$my\'dir -type d -exec sh -c 'ls "{}"' \;
```

It says `./\'dir: No such file or directory`, if I remove the double quotes then it says `unexpected EOF while looking for matching '`.

Comment: Why do you use `sh -c`? `-exec ls {}` should work.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: I know that, because i want to find what is in the directory using `ls {} | grep`.

Comment: I don't get it. You **are** using `find` and in order to examine a directory content you want to use `-exec`, `ls` and `grep`? That seems crazy to me.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: That's not really what i done, I am using `find` to find out all sub-directories that don't contain any pdf files. the command is:`find . -type d ! -exec sh -c 'ls "{}" | grep -qi \.pdf' \; -print`. some directories make that failed, so the question came out, do you have any ideas to do that job?

Comment: May I suggest `mv \$my\ \'dir/ 'my dir'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, some complex solutions here! I think all you need to do is this though:

```
find ./\$my\'dir -type d -exec sh -c 'ls "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Instead of putting the arguments into the `sh` command string, just use them as arguments to `sh`. Note the second `sh` is the value of `$0`, everything after that is a positional argument.

As for your full problem of finding directories not containing pdfs, you are usually always better off using `find` for this kind of thing rather than `ls`. This should be close to what you are looking for:

```
find . -type d \
  -exec sh -c '[ "$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.pdf")" = "" ]' sh {} \; \
  -print
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I think `find ./\$my\'dir -type d -exec sh -c 'ls "$0"' {} \;` also work.

Comment: My thought for not using that was that some shells behave differently depending on the name they are in invoked with. Eg if you invoke bash as `sh`, it enters posix mode. I tested this and it is only for actual executable though, so the above may be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Ok... here is a convoluted way to do it. It'll fail if the filenames contain new line characters.

```
  find . -type d -print0                          \ # get the directory list,
                                                  \ # separated by nulls
| xargs -0 ls -1 -d -Q --quoting-style=shell      \ # pick it with xargs, and use
                                                  \ # ls to apply shell quotes to each
                                                  \ # entry
| xargs -d '\n' -I '{}'                           \
        sh -c "ls {} | grep -qi \.pdf$ || echo {}"  # pick each quoted entry
                                                    # with xargs again
                                                    # (using -d, so it keeps the quotes)
                                                    # and insert it in the string
```

This relies on `ls -Q --quoting-style=shell` quoting with single quotes... otherwise, use single quotes on the argument to `sh -c`.

Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not easily possible because it is not possible to quote arbitrary strings from "outside" only (i.e. by enclosing in `""` or `''`). This could be done by quoting each character with `\` but I don't see how that shall be done with simultaneously calling the shell.

This is possible:

```
echo "$DIR" | sed -e 's/./\\&/g' -e 's/^.*$/echo &/' | bash -s
```

But that cannot be put in an `-exec` statement. And the `echo` cannot be called from a shell because that shell would run into the quoting problem with the argument. You can make the `find` output the shell input:

```
find ./\$my\'dir -type d -print0  | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
```

But: You could write the string to a file and have the shell read it from there:

```
find ./\$my\'dir -maxdepth 0 -type d -fprint tmpfile -exec bash -c 'cat tmpfile' \;
```

Sorry, no, not even that works: `find` opens the file, does the `-exec` action and **afterwards** writes to the file... So... this works but is kind of crazy, of course:

```
find ./\$my\'dir -maxdepth 0 -type d -fprint tmpfile -exec bash -c '(sleep 1; cat tmpfile)&' \;
```

Comment: `sh -c 'echo "$DIR"'` - Gives empty line result `sh -c 'ls "$DIR"'` - Gives `ls: : No such file or directory`

Comment: @PDK Of course, but that has nothing to do with this problem. `sh -c 'ls fubar'` most probably has the same effect. And you have forgotten to export `$DIR`: `export DIR`

Comment: Its already exported as I am getting : `echo $DIR` 
`$my\'dir`

Comment: @PDK My statement was not enough reason for you to just give `export DIR` a try but you prefer to argue with your **interpretation** of the `echo $DIR` output instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem:

```
$ mkdir \$my\'dir
$ touch \$my\'dir/foo
$ ls $DIR
foo
```

As for finding subdirectories that don't include PDF files, just run this:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do 
    [ $(find "$dir" -iname "*.pdf"  | wc -l) -gt 0 ] || echo $dir; 
done
```